# The parameterized complexity of Weighted-CNF-SAT parameterized by the number of clauses

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, satisfiability, 3-sat, parameterized-complexity

What is the parameterized complexity of *Weighted-CNF-SAT*, when parameterized by the **number of clauses**?

**Input:** A CNF formula $\phi$ with $m$ clauses and $n$ variables, and an integer $k$.

**Parameter:** $m$

**Output:** Does there exist an assignment to $\phi$ with hamming weight $k$?

When this problem is parameterized by $k$ it is known to be $W[2]$-Complete.

Is there a known result on this complexity when **parameterized by m**?

Are there any similar results? Perhaps - *CNF-SAT*, parameterized by the number of clauses, or *Weighted-CNF-3SAT*, parameterized by the number of clauses?

Comment: For 3SAT you can simply brute force the solution, so that's trivially FPT.

Comment: There are $\binom{m}{k}$ sets of $k$ clauses, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @PålGD Yes, you are right! Is there a solution though for the non-restricted CNF case? It does not seem to be FPT. However, I wasn't able to prove para-NP/W[1]/W[2] hardness either.